# OpenAccess ORM Fluent API

Tags: orm, telerik, openaccess

Suppose I have an assembly A which has all the entities and mappings using fluent api. this assembly needs enhancing, I get it. but what happens to the assembly which is using assembly A. does it need enhancing too?

thanks

Comment: Actually you only need the entities and a class derived from the FluentMetadataSource, you can have the actual Context defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the project that contains your persistent entities requires enhancement :)  I have videos currently being prepped for upload to [Telerik TV](http://tv.telerik.com), which show the step by step process.  They should be uploaded by the end of today.

-Josh